# Win32 - how I can enter the text into an any window programmatically?

Tags: windows, winapi, textbox, focus

I have an app, which runs in background (stays in the windows tray area) and I need to send keystrokes (usually plain text) to the foreground app, regardless is it normal app or it is an Qt Application, or it is some other app. How can I do it using Win API?

My code work fine for MSVC code editior window, for Notepad, for Wotdpad, for MS Word/Excel, but not work with Qt Creator, Google Chrome and Far file manager.

```
HWND hwndActiveWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
if (hwndActiveWindow==0) 
   {
    return;
   }

DWORD activeWndProcessId = 0, activeWndThreadId = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId( hwndActiveWindow, &activeWndProcessId );

GUITHREADINFO gti = { sizeof(gti) };
if (!GetGUIThreadInfo( activeWndThreadId, &gti ))
   {
    return;
   }

if (gti.hwndCaret==0)
   {
    return;
   }

::std::wstring::size_type i = 0, size = str.size();
for(; i!=size; ++i)
   {
    ::PostMessage( gti.hwndCaret, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)str[i], 1);
   }
```

I need it to work everywhere, for any window, regardless of technology/framework, used for the application. I think I can use clipboard, but it is not a pretty good solution.

Comment: Check out the `SendInput` function.

Answer (score 0):

SendInput with INPUT_KEYBOARD and KEYEVENTF_UNICODE solves the problem.

Note for Qt: for Qt applications it need to send input event two times – first for key press and second with key release (with KEYEVENTF_KEYUP flag). For all other apps it is only need to send key press event, but I think sending two key events is more right.